# Set-Acl only on on files containing certain keyword

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make a powershell script to set permissions to files that contain a certain keyword.

My test code:

```
$NewAcl = Get-Acl perm.txt
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\David\Scripts\test\videos" -Recurse -Filter "testing123" -File | Set-Acl -AclObject $NewAcl -WhatIf
```

I would expect this to set the ACL permission of file *perm.txt* to all files that have keyword "testing123" somewhere in the filename inside folder *C:\Users\David\Scripts\test\videos* but this does not appear to work, any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close all you needed was wild cards added to the filter `*`

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\David\Scripts\test\videos" -Recurse -Filter "*testing123*" -File | Set-Acl -AclObject $NewAcl -WhatIf
```